# Is it possible to set ENV variables for rails development environment in my code?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I know that I can set my ENV variables in bash via

```
export admin_password = "secret"
```

But is there a way to do it in my rails source code somewhere? My first attempt was something like this in `environment/development.rb`

```
ENV['admin_password'] = "secret"
```

But it didn't work. Is there a way to do this?

Comment: Note that the bash command should be `export admin_password="secret"`, not `export admin_password = "secret"`.

Answer (score 88, accepted):

**[Update]**

While the solution under "old answer" will work for general problems, this section is to answer your specific question after clarification from your comment.

You should be able to set environment variables exactly like you specify in your question. As an example, I have a Heroku app that uses HTTP basic authentication.

```
# app/controllers/application_controller.rb
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
  protect_from_forgery
  before_filter :authenticate

  def authenticate
    authenticate_or_request_with_http_basic do |username, password|
      username == ENV['HTTP_USER'] && password == ENV['HTTP_PASS']
    end
  end
end

# config/initializers/dev_environment.rb
unless Rails.env.production?
  ENV['HTTP_USER'] = 'testuser'
  ENV['HTTP_PASS'] = 'testpass'
end
```

So in your case you would use

```
unless Rails.env.production?
  ENV['admin_password'] = "secret"
end
```

Don't forget to restart the server so the configuration is reloaded!

**[Old Answer]**

For app-wide configuration, you might consider a solution like the following:

Create a file `config/application.yml` with a hash of options you want to be able to access:

```
admin_password: something_secret
allow_registration: true
facebook:
  app_id: application_id_here
  app_secret: application_secret_here
  api_key: api_key_here
```

Now, create the file `config/initializers/app_config.rb` and include the following:

```
require 'yaml'

yaml_data = YAML::load(ERB.new(IO.read(File.join(Rails.root, 'config', 'application.yml'))).result)
APP_CONFIG = HashWithIndifferentAccess.new(yaml_data)
```

Now, anywhere in your application, you can access `APP_CONFIG[:admin_password]`, along with all your other data. (Note that since the initializer includes `ERB.new`, your YAML file can contain ERB markup.)

Comment: Well, I'm using Heroku and they allow you to set some ENV variables for things like passwords that you don't want checked into source control. I'm trying to figure out the best thing to do on my dev machine. And yes, I am trying to use the data inside my app.

Comment: Glad to hear it! If you feel an answer is correct, you should mark it by checking the check mark next to the question. It will earn you and the answerer reputation and also help people who find this question in the future locate the correct answer.

Comment: Oh yeah, I'm a new user so it's making me wait 19 hours before I can check it. Still 3 more hours to go :) But thank you for all your help! Actually, if you would edit your answer in removing the `dev_environment.rb` code and replacing it with mine, i'd gladly mark your answer which is much more thorough.

Comment: i like this but for some reason (rails 3 v 4?) couldn't get the app_config.rb to load. I put the code into config/environment.rb and got the same affect. # Load the rails application
require File.expand_path('../application', __FILE__)
require 'yaml'

yaml_data = YAML::load(ERB.new(IO.read(File.join(Rails.root, 'config', 'local_env.yml'))).result)
APP_CONFIG = HashWithIndifferentAccess.new(yaml_data)

# Initialize the rails application
Rails3::Application.initialize!

Comment: Sorry to open such an old thread but wouldn't a setting specific to the dev environment make more sense in the `config/environments/development.rb` file?

Comment: config/initializers/dev_environment.rb is not working when worker is running as cron job.

Comment: has the answer changed with rails 5? I don't have a dev_environment.rb file (not by default anyway)

Comment: For what it's worth. I'm still not thrilled that this solution is suggesting checking even development credentials into the source code. This means that even if it isn't a production "account", whatever those credentials lead to are still accessible by anyone who may happen to gain access to the source code. I'd suggest this isn't a good practice, even for development.

Answer (score 152):

[Never hardcode sensitive information (account credentials, passwords, etc.)](http://www.12factor.net/config). Instead, create a file to store that information as environment variables (key/value pairs), and exclude that file from your source code management system. For example, in terms of Git (source code management system), exclude that file by adding it to .*gitignore*:

```
-bash> echo '/config/app_environment_variables.rb' >> .gitignore
```

**/config/app_environment_variables.rb**

```
ENV['HTTP_USER'] = 'devuser'
ENV['HTTP_PASS'] = 'devpass'
```

As well, add the following lines to `/config/environment.rb`, between the `require` line, and the `Application.initialize` line:

```
# Load the app's custom environment variables here, so that they are loaded before environments/*.rb
app_environment_variables = File.join(Rails.root, 'config', 'app_environment_variables.rb')
load(app_environment_variables) if File.exists?(app_environment_variables)
```

That's it!

As the comment above says, by doing this you will be loading your environment variables before `environments/*.rb`, which means that you will be able to refer to your variables inside those files (e.g. `environments/production.rb`). This is a great advantage over putting your environment variables file inside `/config/initializers/`.

Inside `app_environment_variables.rb` there's no need to distinguish environments as far as *development* or *production* because you will never commit this file into your source code management system, hence it is for the *development* context by default. But if you need to set something special for the *test* environment (or for occasions when you test *production* mode *locally*), just add a conditional block *below* all the other variables:

```
if Rails.env.test?
  ENV['HTTP_USER'] = 'testuser'
  ENV['HTTP_PASS'] = 'testpass'
end

if Rails.env.production?
  ENV['HTTP_USER'] = 'produser'
  ENV['HTTP_PASS'] = 'prodpass'
end
```

Whenever you update `app_environment_variables.rb`, restart the app server. Assuming you are using the likes of Apache/Passenger or `rails server`:

```
-bash> touch tmp/restart.txt
```

In your code, refer to the environment variables as follows:

```
def authenticate
  authenticate_or_request_with_http_basic do |username, password|
    username == ENV['HTTP_USER'] && password == ENV['HTTP_PASS']
  end
end
```

Note that inside `app_environment_variables.rb` you must specify *booleans* and *numbers* as *strings* (e.g. `ENV['SEND_MAIL'] = 'false'` not just `false`, and `ENV['TIMEOUT'] = '30'` not just `30`), otherwise you will get the errors `can't convert false into String` and `can't convert Fixnum into String`, respectively.

**Storing and sharing sensitive information**

The final knot to tie is: *how to share this sensitive information with your clients and/or partners?* For the purpose of business continuity (i.e. when you get hit by a falling star, how will your clients and/or partners resume full operations of the site?), your clients and/or partners need to know all the credentials required by your app. Emailing/Skyping these things around is insecure and leads to disarray. Storing it in shared Google Docs is not bad (if everyone uses https), but an app dedicated to storing and sharing small titbits like passwords would be ideal.

**How to set environment variables on Heroku**

If you have a single environment on Heroku:

```
-bash> heroku config:add HTTP_USER='herouser'
-bash> heroku config:add HTTP_USER='heropass'
```

If you have [multiple environments](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/multiple-environments) on Heroku:

```
-bash> heroku config:add HTTP_USER='staguser' --remote staging
-bash> heroku config:add HTTP_PASS='stagpass' --remote staging

-bash> heroku config:add HTTP_USER='produser' --remote production
-bash> heroku config:add HTTP_PASS='prodpass' --remote production
```

**Foreman and .env**

[Many developers use Foreman](https://rubygems.org/gems/foreman) (installed with the [Heroku Toolbelt](http://toolbelt.heroku.com/)) to [run their apps locally](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/config-vars#local-setup) (as opposed to using the likes of Apache/Passenger or `rails server`). Foreman and Heroku use [`Procfile` for declaring what commands are run by your application](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/procfile), so the transition from local dev to Heroku is seamless in that regard. I use Foreman and Heroku in every Rails project, so this convenience is great. But here's the thing.. [Foreman loads environment variables stored in `/.env` via dotenv](https://github.com/ddollar/foreman/blob/master/lib/foreman/engine.rb#L172) but unfortunately [dotenv essentially only parses the file for `key=value` pairs](https://github.com/bkeepers/dotenv/blob/master/lib/dotenv/environment.rb); those pairs don't become variables right there and then, so you can't refer to already set variables (to keep things DRY), nor can you do "Ruby" in there (as noted above with the conditionals), which you can do in `/config/app_environment_variables.rb`. For instance, in terms of keeping things DRY I sometimes do stuff like this:

```
ENV['SUPPORT_EMAIL']='Company Support <support@company.com>'
ENV['MAILER_DEFAULT_FROM'] = ENV['SUPPORT_EMAIL']
ENV['MAILER_DEFAULT_TO']   = ENV['SUPPORT_EMAIL']
```

Hence, I use Foreman to run my apps locally, but I don't use its `.env` file for loading environment variables; rather I use Foreman in conjunction with the `/config/app_environment_variables.rb` approach described above.

Comment: I like this solution as I wanted to be sure that sensitive settings (API keys etc) are adequately protected in a keystore, instead of in clear text and not bundled with the Git repository. Thanks.

Answer (score 13):

The way I am trying to do this in my question actually works!

```
# environment/development.rb

ENV['admin_password'] = "secret"
```

I just had to restart the server. I thought running `reload!` in rails console would be enough but I also had to restart the web server.

I am picking my own answer because I feel this is a better place to put and set the ENV variables

Comment: Glad you found out why it wasn't working! I personally like to save `config/application.rb` and `config/environments/*.rb` for setting up the *Rails* environment and using other methods to set up my *application* environment, but that certainly doesn't mean it's the only way (or even the "right" way :)

Comment: I was thrown off a little because I was trying to set things differently between production and development. But now I completely agree with you! Thanks for not only answering my original question but helping me understand the rails app structure better!

Answer (score 8):

As an aside to the solutions here, there are cleaner alternatives if you're using certain development servers.

With Heroku's [Foreman](https://github.com/ddollar/foreman), you can create per-project environment variables in a `.env` file:

```
ADMIN_PASSOWRD="secret"
```

With [Pow](http://pow.cx/), you can use a `.powenv` file:

```
export ADMIN_PASSOWRD="secret"
```

Answer (score 3):

I think the best way is to store them in some yml file and then load that file using this command in intializer file

```
APP_CONFIG = YAML.load_file("#{Rails.root}/config/CONFIG.yml")[Rails.env].to_hash
```

you can easily access environment related config variables.

Your Yml file key value structure:

```
development:
  app_key: 'abc'
  app_secret: 'abc'

production:
  app_key: 'xyz'
  app_secret: 'ghq'
```

Answer (score 2):

You can also use the `dotenv` or `dotenv-rails` rails gems, e.g.

Have a `.env` with:

```sh
HTTP_USER=user
HTTP_PASSWORD=password
```

The nice thing is you can have `.env.development`, `.env.production`, `.env.development.local`, etc.

https://github.com/bkeepers/dotenv

Answer (score 1):

The system environment and rails' environment are different things. `ENV` let's you work with the rails' environment, but if what you want to do is to change the system's environment in runtime you can just surround the command with backticks.

```
# ruby code
`export admin_password="secret"`
# more ruby code
```

Comment: Just a note that `export` will complain about the spaces; try `export admin_password="secret"`

Comment: I forgot that (very important) detail. Corrected my answer, thanks!

Comment: This doesn't work since backticks spawn a subshell and variables you set in the subshell can't affect the environment of the parent.

Comment: Nope, it does work. The answer, as clearly explained, is not targeted at the environment of the parent. There are perfectly good answers which instruct on how to do that.

Answer (score 1):

Script for loading of custom `.env` file:
Add the following lines to `/config/environment.rb`, between the `require` line, and the `Application.initialize` line:

```
# Load the app's custom environment variables here, so that they are loaded before environments/*.rb

app_environment_variables = File.join(Rails.root, 'config', 'local_environment.env')
if File.exists?(app_environment_variables)
  lines = File.readlines(app_environment_variables)
  lines.each do |line|
    line.chomp!
    next if line.empty? or line[0] == '#'
    parts = line.partition '='
    raise "Wrong line: #{line} in #{app_environment_variables}" if parts.last.empty?
    ENV[parts.first] = parts.last
  end
end
```

And `config/local_environment.env` (you will want to `.gitignore` it) will look like:

```
# This is ignored comment
DATABASE_URL=mysql2://user:psw@0.0.0:3307/database
RACK_ENV=development
```

(Based on solution of @user664833)

Answer (score 1):

Add In your Gemfile `gem 'dotenv-rails'`
run command `bundle install`
add .env file in you root directory and write your environment variable like

```
export RAILS_ENV=production && rails c
```

export AUTH="xyz 891f5089ba563cd1ea55b73467"

call the env from anywhere in you application also you rails console
run `rails console`
write `ENV['AUTH']`
then press enter, you will find your result `xyz 891f5089ba563cd1ea55b73467`

Answer (score 1):

For many years I relied on the [Figaro](https://github.com/laserlemon/figaro) gem, but it has unfortunately not been maintained. The latest problem there, [Psych::BadAlias](https://github.com/laserlemon/figaro/issues/289) led me to roll my own solution.

This turned out to be pretty simple and I continue to use the `application.yml` file originally defined for Figaro.

#### `config/environments/development.rb`

Load the variables when the app boots. The same code can be used in `test.rb` for local tests and CI.

```rb
Rails.application.configure do
  env_file = File.join(Rails.root, 'config', 'application.yml')
  YAML.load_file(env_file).symbolize_keys[:development].each do |key, value|
    ENV[key.to_s] = value
  end
  ...
```

#### `lib/tasks/heroku.rake`

```rb
namespace :myapp do
  desc 'Push from `application.yml to Heroku`'
  task push_config: :environment do
    app = 'myapp-prd'

    env_file = File.join(Rails.root, 'config', 'application.yml')
    YAML.load_file(env_file).symbolize_keys[:production].each do |key, value|
      sh "heroku config:add #{key.to_s}='#{value}' --app #{app}"
    end
  end
end
```

The only issue is it reloads the Heroku environment after every variable is loaded. This can be optimised, but in reality ENV variables are not changed much anyway.

Answer (score 0):

There are already excellent answers. Throwing my own poor man's dotenv in the ring with only one new idea: Using an allow list for keys spares us many hairy string issues which can arise and trivially discards commented lines. This also handles quoted values in the .env (although poorly):

```rb
# in config/environment.rb

if Rails.root.join(".env").exist?
  allow_keys = ["STORAGE_BUCKET", "SECRET_KEY"]
  Rails.root.join(".env").readlines.filter{|s| s.match("=")}.map{|s| s.split("=", 2)}.each do |key, value|
    ENV[key.strip] = value.strip.gsub(/^["']/, '').gsub(/["']$/, '') if allow_keys.include?(key.strip)
  end
end
```

Then use a file `.env` in your app root and add `.env` to your `.gitignore`