# Getting OmniAuth provider settings

Tags: ruby-on-rails, omniauth

I have OmniAuth setup to use Twitter like so:

```
Rails.application.config.middleware.use OmniAuth::Builder do
  provider :twitter, 'key', 'secret'
end
```

How do I retrieve the OmniAuth settings for the Twitter key and secret somewhere else my my app, like in a model?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of inserting the key and secret in the middleware declaration as a string, you could setup a constant in an initializer and refer to the key/secret using the constant in both the middleware and elsewhere in your app.

Comment: Ah yes, that definitely seems like the proper way to do it. Thanks bensie!

Comment: +1 I prefer to use a YAML config file; see "old answer" at [this SO link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4911607/is-it-possible-to-set-env-variables-for-rails-development-environment-in-my-code/4911647#4911647)

Comment: I found that Settingslogic (https://github.com/binarylogic/settingslogic) is a great solution to this.