# Where to put environment variables when using nginx and Passenger on Ubuntu

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ubuntu, environment-variables

I was trying to set up a system similar to heroku where I would store secret keys in environmental variables and then access them from my rails app like this:

```
secret = ENV['EMAIL_PASSWORD']
```

I know heroku lets you do `heroku config:add EMAIL_PASSWORD=secret`, and I wanted to do something like that for my own ubuntu box running nginx and Passenger.

Should I add these variables as `export`s in `.bashrc` or `.bash_login` so that on system reboot these variables are automatically set?

I'm not sure when each of those files gets read in.

Answer (score 10):

You can use [dotenv gem](https://github.com/bkeepers/dotenv) which loads the .env file as environmental variables. You can generate the .env file for different environments, and need not be rather should not checked into your repository.

Comment: I'm using dotenv for another project, it's something you use for test and development normally. Suppose I could use it for production to, I like the .env listing all the env vars, it's neat. Are you doing this?

Comment: No. I've not used it. I've used Heroku Config settings and that looked really neat to me. Got this idea from the the following blog post: http://daniel.fone.net.nz/blog/2013/05/20/a-better-way-to-manage-the-rails-secret-token/

Answer (score 8):

Keep in mind that nginx may not be running under the same environment as you are, and usually (pronounced "Apache") we add env-vars in the server config file via SetEnv. However, nginx doesn't have such a feature... nor does it need one, I believe.

```
sudo -E /usr/local/sbin/nginx
```

When running nginx for it to be aware of your own user env vars.

Or, check out the `env` command ([see here](http://wiki.nginx.org/CoreModule)):

```
env EMAIL_PASSWORD=secret
```

To answer your question, yes, you should use `export` statements in your shell config files.

Answer (score 6):

(this is probably a overkill, but maybe it'll be useful)

Some things to keep in mind:

Environment variables are somewhat public, and can be seen by other processes as easily as added an option to the `ps(1)` command (like `ps e $$` in bash) or looking at `/proc/*/environ`, though both are restricted at least to the same user (or root) on modern systems.  Don't rely on them being secret if you have another fairly easy option available.

`~/.bashrc` is the wrong place for environment variables, since they can be computed once at login in `~/.bash_login`, ~/.bash_profile, or `~/.profile`, depending on your usage, and passed down to all descendent shells.  In contrast, `~/.bashrc` actions tend to be recomputed on every shell invocation (unless explicitly disabled).

Putting bash code in the `~/.profile` can confuse other sh-descendent shells and non-shell tools which try to read that file, so having the bash-specific `~/.bash_login` or -_profile contain the bash-specific things, and using `. ~/.profile` for the more general things (LESS, EDITOR, VISUAL, LC_COLLATE, LS_COLORS, etc), is friendlier to the other tools.

Environment variables in `~/.profile` should be in the old Bourne shell form (`VAR=value ; export VAR`).  On Linux, this isn't usually critical, though on other Unixen this can be a big issue when an older version of "sh" tries to read them.

Some X sessions will only read `~/.profile`, not `~/.bash_login` or the others mentioned above. Some will look for a `~/.xsession` file will need to be modified to have `. $HOME/.profile` if it doesn't already somehow.

System-wide settings would be put instead in something like `/etc/profile.d/similar-to-heroku.sh`.  Note that the ".sh" is only present since the file will be used with "." or "source" - shell scripts should *never* have command-name extensions in any form of Unix/Linux.

Most environment variables get ditched when one `sudo`s to root, as ybakos points out.  Similar issues show up in crontabs, at jobs, etc.  When in doubt, adding `env | sort > /tmp/envvars` or the like a suspect script can really help in debugging.

Be aware some distributions have shell startup scripts so contorted they end up actually defying the order given in the bash(1) manual page.  Anytime you find a default user `~/.profile` checking for $BASH or $BASH_VERSION, you may be in one of these, um..., "interesting" environments, and may have to read through them to figure out where the control flow goes (they should be using a bash-specific `~/.bash_profile` or `~/.bash_login`, which includes the more generic `~/.profile` by reference, thus letting the bash executable do the work instead of having to write $BASH checks in shell code).

`~/.bash_profile` (or `~/.bash_login`) can certainly include `. ~/.bashrc`, but the environment variables belong in the `~/.bash_profile` (if bash-specific) or the `~/.profile` included from it (if you're using this mechanism and have envvars for everything else in there) as DeWitt says, just remember to put the `. ~/.bashrc` AFTER the .bash_profile's `. ~/.profile` and other environment variables, so that both login and all other invocations of the `~/.bashrc` can rely on the envvars already being set.  An Example `~/.bash_profile`:

```
# .bash_profile
[ -r ~/.profile ] && . ~/.profile  # envvars
[ -r ~/.bashrc ]  && . ~/.bashrc   # functions, per-tty settings, etc.
#---eof
```

The `[ -r ... ] && ...` works in any Bourne shell descendent and doesn't cause errors/aborts if the .profile is missing (I personally have a `~/.profile.d/*.sh` setup as well, but this is left as an entirely optional exercise).

Note that bash only reads the first file of these three which it finds:

```
~/.bash_profile
~/.bash_login
~/.profile
```

...so once you have that one, the use of the other two is entirely under control of the user, from bash's perspective.

Comment: This is probably somewhere in your answer but I couldn't decipher it: what's your recommendation as to where to actually put the environment variables?

Answer (score 6):

[This is documented in nginx](http://wiki.nginx.org/CoreModule#env). It removes all environment variables **except** `TZ` when running the workers. If you want to add an environment variable, add the following to the **top** of the nginx configuration:

```
# The top of the configuration usually has things like:
user user-name;
pid pid-file-name;

# Add to this:
env VAR1=value1;
env VAR2=value2;

# OR simply add:
env VAR1;
# To inherit the VAR1 from whatever you set in bash
```

The normal `export` or anything you do in bash has no guarantee of getting passed on to nginx, due to the way the init scripts are written (we don't know if they're using sudo with a clean environment, etc). So I'd rather put these in the nginx configuration file itself, rather than depending on the shell to do it.

Edit: Fix link

Comment: are you positive about this? is this how you do it yourself?

Comment: Its much better than storing in .bashrc or .bash_login. `.bashrc`/`.bash_login` are user-specific and not guaranteed to be called in certain circumstances (say when you use sudo, or from an upstart script, etc)

Comment: env in nginx is different from ENV available to rails, right? Is this a validated answer or not (meaning your doing it)?

Comment: I had to downvote because as @oma stated, rails apps do not have access to the variables you set in the nginx config. I have tried to set a few variables exactly as you explained...and it does not work. If you consider expanding on your answer, I will upvote again.

Comment: If you use `passenger_env_var` command in your nginx config then environment variables will be setup by passenger, and thus accessible by your rails app. See my answer.

Answer (score 5):

I put them in my nginx config, specifically in the server definition for the app using the `passenger_env_var` command:

```
server {
    server_name www.foo.com;
    root /webapps/foo/public;
    passenger_enabled on;

    passenger_env_var DATABASE_USERNAME foo_db;
    passenger_env_var DATABASE_PASSWORD secret;
    passenger_env_var SECRET_KEY_BASE the_secret_keybase;
}
```

This works for me. See the phusion passenger [docs](https://www.phusionpassenger.com/library/config/nginx/reference/#passenger_env_var) for more info.

Comment: Didn't do anything for me, still showing that I'm not using a password for mysql2, app works just fine if I replace <%=ENV["MYSQL_P"]%> with my password.

Comment: What version of nginx are you using? `passenger_env_var` was added in version 5.0.0. Prior versions won't support it.

Comment: root@server:~# passenger-config --version

Phusion Passenger 5.0.30

Comment: I ended up having to edit my RVM package manager's environment config file to include the user's .bashrc file

Comment: This works but you need to remember the vars will *only* be accessed by Passenger. Performing local operations (`rake assets:precompile` etc) will not pick them up

Answer (score 4):

I have a script in `/usr/local/bin` folder that sets some env vars and then executes Ruby.  I define the path to Ruby in my (Apache, not Nginx) conf file to that file in `/usr/local/bin`.

example:

```
#!/bin/sh

# setup env vars here
export FOO=bar
export PATH_TO_FOO=/bar/bin
export PATH=$PATH:PATH_TO_FOO

# and execute Ruby with any arguments passed to this script
exec "/usr/bin/ruby" "$@"
```

Answer (score 2):

You should read this response to another question, it will help:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/11765775/1217298

Answer (score 1):

EDITED :

Ok sorry i read it too fast, you can check how to save your ENV variables here :

https://help.ubuntu.com/community/EnvironmentVariables

http://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/set-environment-variable-linux/

If you use Nginx as server on your local computer, you can define your env variable into your nginx config file.

```
location / {
...
   fastcgi_param   EMAIL_PASSWORD  secret; #EMAIL_PASSWORD = secret
...
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm using rbenv as a version manager. Good solution to store environment variables for the project was installing the [rbenv-vars](https://github.com/sstephenson/rbenv-vars) plugin and putting them in `.rbenv-vars` file.

Here is a useful post:
[Deploying app ENV variables with Rbenv, Passenger and Capistrano](https://intercityup.com/blog/deploying-app-env-variables-with-rbenv-passenger-and-capistrano.html)

Answer (score 1):

For those battling this that are using RVM. Make sure that your default environments file is including your user's .bashrc and .profile files

```
file: $rvm_path/environments/default
```

to find the path run this command:

```
ls -lah `whereis rvm`/environments/default
```

add these two lines before the first line in that file:

```
source $HOME/.bashrc
source $HOME/.profile
```

Answer (score 1):

The best place to keep env variables for your project is /etc/profile.d/YOUR_FILE.sh,
[Here](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/EnvironmentVariables) you can find the documentation which explains in details where to keep env variables for different scenarios.

Answer (score 0):

In case anyone had the same type of question as I did, here's a nice little writeup about the different `.bash*` files: http://www.joshstaiger.org/archives/2005/07/bash_profile_vs.html

In summary:

For the most part:
`.bash_profile` is read when you log into the computer and `.bashrc` is read when you start a new terminal.  For Mac OSX `.bash_profile` is read with every terminal window you start.

So, the recommended procedure is to source `.bashrc` from `.bash_profile` so all the variables are set when you login to the computer.  Just add this to `.bash_profile`:

```
if [ -f ~/.bashrc ]; then
   source ~/.bashrc
fi
```

Answer (score -1):

You have to add the export lines into your .profile file under your home folder...

Environment variables are being set on login...

Comment: does a login happen after a reboot when nginx is started by an rc.d script?