# Change Twitter provider after initialization with Omniauth gem

Tags: ruby-on-rails, twitter, omniauth

I'm using Omniauth to authenticate at Twitter, but I have 2 apps registred with diferent names that I want to use depeding on the current locale(session scope).

So I need to change the provider key and secret defined at omniauth.rb file right before user calls auth/twitter( I was thinking to do a before_filter but auth/twitter is an external link to twitter and not a regular action) or a way to config Omniauth to define providers by locale instead of define for the entire application scope.

So how can I do that ? Any idea?

Comment: This should be enough to send you in the right direction: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4911607/is-it-possible-to-set-env-variables-for-rails-development-environment-in-my-code/4911647#4911647

Comment: I know that Omniauth is a rack middleware, how to access that throught a env variable?

Answer (score 0):

What you need to do is set setup to true in omniauth builder

```
  Rails.application.config.middleware.use OmniAuth::Builder do
    provider :twitter , :setup => true
  end
```

Then set add following to your routes.rb file to define which route will be called for setup

```
  get '/people/auth/twitter/setup' => 'sessions#twitter_setup' #needed for devise setup phase hook to work
```

After so just set the omniauth strategy in the session controller that meet the route for setup

```
def twitter_setup
  request.env['omniauth.strategy'].options[:consumer_key] = YOUR_DYNAMIC_KEY
    request.env['omniauth.strategy'].options[:consumer_secret] = YOUR_DYNAMIC_SECRET_KEY
    render :plain => "Setup complete.", :status => 404
end
```

this will enable you to load the apps you need