# Where to set environment variables such that they can be read from `config/initializer/*.rb`?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3.1, environment-variables

I have all my environment variables in `config/initializers/app_environment_variables.rb` and this setup has been working so far, except now I need to use the variables in `config/environments.rb` and `config/environments/*.rb`, which seem to be executed before `config/initializer/*.rb`.

I found [this](http://www.sekuda.com/rails_initialization_and_configuration_order) page showing "the configuration order" as the following,

1. config/preinitializer.rb
2. config/environment.rb
3. config/environments/#{RAILS_ENV}.rb
4. plugin initialization
5. gem initialization
6. config/initializer/*.rb
7. ...

but that info is from 2009, whereas I am on `Rails 3.1`. I expected to see this kind of info in the "[initialization](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/initialization.html)" or the "[configuring](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/configuring.html)" guides, but either I was unable to find the info, or it's not there.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I added `puts "--- #{__FILE__}"` to the top of each of the following files in a new "demo" app (`rails new demo`):

```
config.ru
config/application.rb
config/boot.rb
config/environment.rb
config/environments/development.rb
config/initializers/hello.rb
```

Then I simply started the app with `rails server`, and got the following output (`....` for terseness):

```
--- /Volumes/..../initialization-order/demo/config/boot.rb
--- /Volumes/..../initialization-order/demo/config/application.rb
=> Booting WEBrick
=> Rails 3.2.13 application starting in development on http://0.0.0.0:3000
=> Call with -d to detach
=> Ctrl-C to shutdown server
--- /Volumes/..../initialization-order/demo/config.ru
--- /Volumes/..../initialization-order/demo/config/environment.rb
--- /Volumes/..../initialization-order/demo/config/environments/development.rb
--- /Volumes/..../initialization-order/demo/config/initializers/hello.rb
[2013-05-16 15:05:59] INFO  WEBrick 1.3.1
[2013-05-16 15:05:59] INFO  ruby 1.9.3 (2013-02-22) [x86_64-darwin12.3.0]
[2013-05-16 15:05:59] INFO  WEBrick::HTTPServer#start: pid=91029 port=3000
^C[2013-05-16 15:06:25] INFO  going to shutdown ...
[2013-05-16 15:06:25] INFO  WEBrick::HTTPServer#start done.
Exiting
```

Therefore the initialization order is as follows:

```
/config/boot.rb
/config/application.rb
/config.ru
/config/environment.rb
/config/environments/development.rb
/config/initializers/hello.rb
```

So if you want your environment variables loaded before `config/environments/*.rb` (and before `/config/initializers/*.rb`) then [read this next](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11765775/664833).

Answer (score 2):

I recommend using [foreman](https://github.com/ddollar/foreman) and a `.env` file to set your environment variables.

1. Create a `.env.sample` file that goes into source control
2. Create your own `.env` file, and add `.env` to `.gitignore`
3. Use `foreman start` rather than `rails s`
4. enjoy the awesomeness (defaults to port 5000).

**.env.sample**

```
AWS_ACCESS_ID=YOUR_ACCESSKEY_GOES_HERE
ETC_ETC=ETC ETC ETC
```

Benefits:

- You won't be committing your sensitive information to source control.
- They truly will be environment variables, set before any code is ever run.

Comment: If you edited the answer -- any feedback? Did this work for you?

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I do intend to try your suggestion, though I ended up going with a slight variation on what I was already doing. I now host my ENV variables in `config/app_environment_variables.rb` and I added two lines to `config/environment.rb` to load that file before `environments/*.rb`. [Here's my current setup.](http://stackoverflow.com/a/11765775) Again, I do intend to return to your answer.

Comment: I got tripped up by what you said in point #3: "rather than `rails s`". I am not using `rails server` as far as I know (at least not directly); I am using Apache/Passenger, and can simply load any of my rails apps in a browser with a URL like `http://app_name.local/`. Sorry that I don't understand this. Could you kindly clarify point #3 (and #4, I suppose, re: port 5000, and why I need to know that)? Thank you.

Comment: @user664833 If you're using .local, then you're using POW. use this: http://pow.cx/manual.html#section_2.2

Comment: I am not using POW. The `.local` in `app_name.local` is simply part of my preference for the `ServerName` in my Passenger setup.

Comment: OK. I recommend using foreman or pow rather than Apache/Passenger. However, if you are using passenger and RVM, you can add your environmental variables to the RVM Passenger load script. But I recommend using foreman or pow locally.

Comment: This approach has two disadvantages from my point of view: (1) the variables are not loaded into `rails console`, and (2) there is no notion of "comments", so I cannot make comments or comment out lines.

Comment: @user664833 check out https://github.com/rwz/heroku-dev-env then. Appears to support comments and don't have to run `heroku run rails console`

Comment: Thanks a lot (for real). I am now using Foreman for running my applications locally (as opposed to formerly using Apache/Passenger), but at this time I just don't see the advantage of using Foreman's `.env` for environment variables, when compared to [my config/app_environment_variables.rb approach](http://stackoverflow.com/a/11765775). The `heroku-dev-env` suggestion is not bad, but again, I see no advantage over what I am doing, except perhaps not having to add two lines to `/config/environment.rb`. Do you see any other disadvantages to my approach?

Comment: As long as you're not committing the variables to source control, it's all good

Comment: there is also dotenv gem worth checking out

Comment: [Foreman uses the dotenv gem](https://github.com/ddollar/foreman/blob/master/lib/foreman/engine.rb#L172), and though [dotenv now ignores blank lines and comments](https://github.com/bkeepers/dotenv/commit/6bba88d448cd79578f5bc7ece45142a11338973d) it is not interpreted as Ruby, it's just parsed, so it is not possible to refer back to already set "variables" (so as to keep things DRY). So I still prefer the `config/app_environment_variables.rb` [approach](http://stackoverflow.com/a/11765775).