# Omniauth authentication fails in Rails 4

Tags: ruby, omniauth, ruby-on-rails-4

I am working in rails 4 and I am trying to authenticate using github. So in my Github application I have this:

> URL: http:// localhost:4000
>
> Callback URL: http:// localhost:4000/auth/github/callback

The callback url is the url that Github will try to reach when the authentication is done right?

So why do I get a Github page 404 error when I click on my link:

```
<%= link_to 'Sign in with Github', '/auth/github' %>
```

I am working on a localhost development enviroment so that might be the problem?

Also when i type `http:// localhost:4000/auth/github/callback` on my browser I get an OmniAuth::Strategies::OAuth2::CallbackError

why? I have this in my routes.rb

```
post 'auth/:provider/callback' => 'home#index'
```

Is Rails 4 and Omniauth bugged?
(added the space in localhost so stackoverflow accepts my post)

Answer (score 0):

I have github working with the gem `omniauth-github`
and a file `config/initializers/omniauth.rb` containing

```
Rails.application.config.middleware.use OmniAuth::Builder do
    provider :github, ENV['GITHUB_KEY'], ENV['GITHUB_SECRET']
end
```

However, when I enter `http://localhost:3000/auth/github/callback` on my browser I also get `OmniAuth::Strategies::OAuth2::CallbackError` so this shouldn't be the problem.

My `config/environment.rb` looks like

```
# Load the rails application
require File.expand_path('../application', __FILE__)

# Load the app's custom environment variables here, so that they are loaded before environments/*.rb
app_environment_variables = File.join(Rails.root, 'config', 'app_environment_variables.rb')
load(app_environment_variables) if File.exists?(app_environment_variables)

...
```

and my `config/app/environment_variables.rb` looks like

```
# OAuth Keys and Secrets
if Rails.env.production?
  ENV['GITHUB_KEY'] = 'd1234a3a123a1a3a123c'
  ENV['GITHUB_SECRET'] = '1234azer123azer1231209jeunsghezkndaz1234'
else
  ENV['GITHUB_KEY'] = 'qsflkjkj685bg554456b'
  ENV['GITHUB_SECRET'] = 'qslkfj7757kqfmlsdh675hlfsd587kjfdh687jsd'
end
```

See [Is it possible to set ENV variables for rails development environment in my code?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4911607/is-it-possible-to-set-env-variables-for-rails-development-environment-in-my-code) for more details on that.
I have 2 applications registered on github. One `app_name-dev` with key `qsflk...`, url `http://localhost:3000` and callback url `http://localhost:3000/auth/github/callback` and one `app_name` with key `d1234a...`.

Check that you have done that correctly. Maybe try to change `localhost` to `127.0.0.1`.

Answer (score 0):

For me it was Github's new stricter URI matching that was producing a 404 when trying to redirect to `http://localhost:3000/auth/github/callback`, I solved it by passing the redirect URI as a parameter with Omniauth.

```
Rails.application.config.middleware.use OmniAuth::Builder do
    provider :github, ENV['GITHUB_KEY'], ENV['GITHUB_SECRET'], 
        :scope => 'user,public_repo', 
        :redirect_uri => ENV['GITHUB_REDIRECT']
end
```

If your on Linux/Mac you can add environment variables from the command line.

```
$ export GITHUB_REDIRECT=http://localhost:3000/auth/github/callback
```

Alternatively, you could use something like [Foreman](http://ddollar.github.io/foreman/) that will let you add a .env file which you can use to store your variables in.

Just remember to add the appropriate redirect URI to your production environment's variables, and you're good, to go.