# Error while Encoding access and secret s3 on yaml file

Tags: ruby-on-rails, encoding, yaml

To avoid passing in access keys and secret aws access on a yml file I use the following :

```
development:
  bucket: development
  access_key_id: <%= ENV["S3_KEY"] %>
  secret_access_key: <%= ENV["S3_SECRET"] %>
```

and then when running i get the error

```
Could not log "sql.active_record" event. ArgumentError: invalid byte sequence in UTF-8
PG::Error: ERROR:  invalid byte sequence for encoding "UTF8": 0xe7 0xe3 0x6f
```

If I write my access key and secret directly on yml, like:

```
development:
  bucket: development
  access_key_id: MYACCESSKEY
  secret_access_key: MYSECRETKEY
```

it goes smoothly.

Why does this error happen? How can i fix it without loading my key and secret into the yml file?

**Edit**

To load the environment variables onto development, I'm using the solution explained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11765775/1461972)

```
# Load the app's custom environment variables here, so that they are loaded before environments/*.rb
app_environment_variables = File.join(Rails.root, 'config', 'app_environment_variables.rb')
load(app_environment_variables) if File.exists?(app_environment_variables)
```

Might this be a problem with the loading process?

**Edit 2**

In the meanwhile, I tried to log what seems to be on my S3_CONFIG variable, loaded with:

config/initializers/load_config.rb

```
S3_CONFIG = YAML.load_file("#{::Rails.root}/config/s3.yml")[Rails.env]
```

I get

```
S3 Config: {"bucket"=>"mybucket", "access_key_id"=>"<%= ENV[\"S3_KEY\"] %>", "secret_access_key"=>"<%= ENV[\"S3_SECRET\"] %>"}
```

Wasn't it supposed to load the environment key already? May this be my problem?

Comment: Did you actually set ENV["S3_KEY"] somewhere in your app?

Comment: yes, I'm using the solution on the second answer of [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4911607/is-it-possible-to-set-env-variables-for-rails-development-environment-in-my-code) question.

Comment: I've added new info to the question, to make it clearer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This problem was happening when I was downloading the file from S3 with :

```
s3=AWS::S3.new(
      access_key_id: S3_CONFIG["access_key_id"],
      secret_access_key: S3_CONFIG["secret_access_key"])
```

and `S3_CONFIG["access_key_id"]` is just a string `<%= ENV[\"S3_KEY\"] %>`.

My solution for this was using just

```
s3=AWS::S3.new(
      access_key_id: ENV['S3_KEY'],
      secret_access_key: ENV['S3_SECRET'])
```

Guess sometimes one just needs to understand what he is doing, before pasting in lines of code...