# Rails + OmniAuth Facebook: how to obtain Access Token?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, facebook, omniauth, access-token

I am trying to fetch the list of friends from Facebook. Sign in through Facebook is not a problem, but the problem is to fetch person's friends - because of `access token`.

```
puts request.env["omniauth.auth"].inspect
puts '==='
@user = User.find_for_facebook_oauth(request.env["omniauth.auth"], current_user)
@fb_user = FbGraph::User.fetch(@user.uid).friends
puts @fb_user.inspect
```

The problem is on the #4 line - in this case I am getting error

```
OAuthException :: An access token is required to request this resource.
```

When I put there something like this:

```
@fb_user = FbGraph::User.fetch(request.env["omniauth.auth"].credentials.token).friends
```

I'll get

```
OAuthException :: (#803) Some of the aliases you requested do not exist: PRINTED OUT TOKEN
```

What's the proper way to obtain the `access token`?

### **EDIT: Current flow**

```
class Users::OmniauthCallbacksController < Devise::OmniauthCallbacksController
  def facebook
    @user = User.find_for_facebook_oauth(request.env["omniauth.auth"], current_user)
    @fb_user = FbGraph::User.fetch(request.env["omniauth.auth"].credentials.token).friends
    if !@user
      flash[:error] = 'This email address is already used in the system.'
      redirect_to :back
    elsif @user.persisted?
      flash[:notice] = I18n.t "devise.omniauth_callbacks.success", :kind => "Facebook"
      sign_in_and_redirect @user, :event => :authentication
    else
      session["devise.facebook_data"] = request.env["omniauth.auth"]
      redirect_to new_user_registration_url
    end
  end
```

In **User** model:

```
  def self.find_for_facebook_oauth(access_token, signed_in_resource=nil)
    data = access_token.extra.raw_info
    if user = User.where(:provider => 'facebook', :uid => data.id).first
      user
    elsif user = User.where('email = ? AND provider IS NULL', data.email).first
      return false
    else
      ...saving data...
    end
    return user if user
  end
```

Answer (score 4):

You can get an access token for test purposes via the [Facebook Graph API Explorer](https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer/). Make sure you select the proper fields that you want access to, and click "get access token". A more permanent solution is to register your app with Facebook so that you will be able to continually make requests without the token dying.

You should look into the [Facebook OAuth dialogue](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/dialogs/oauth/).

I'm assuming you're trying to use the OAuth2 strategy instead of the Javascript SDK. Make sure you have set up a callback url like so:

```
client.redirect_uri = "http://your.client.com/facebook/callback"
```

In the controller that handles your callback, you should do something like this:

```
client.authorization_code = params[:code] 
access_token = client.access_token! :client_auth_body 
FbGraph::User.me(access_token).fetch
```

Make sure you've let fb_graph know what your app's id and secret are. You should look into [this stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4911607/is-it-possible-to-set-env-variables-for-rails-development-environment-in-my-code) to keep your apps info safe.

I'll also plug the [koala gem](https://github.com/arsduo/koala)

Comment: Thanks man for the answer. I have registered Facebook app on developers.facebook.com. I am using **fb_graph** gem. What I need to allow in the Facebook app to automatically receive the access token?

Comment: You should be able to find your app's id and secret on the developers.facebook.com site -- both of which are required for the login process, I believe. Be sure to check out the [Facebook login flow](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/). To address your problem specifically, you need to use your app's id and secret as well as as a callback location for Facebook to send the other parts of the handshake. Review [this page](https://github.com/nov/fb_graph#authentication) of the fb_graph gem.

Comment: Hi `akells`, I added to the original post the current flow of Facebook authentication. I don't understand the thing about redirect - how I should redirect the user? When he'll be redirected from FB to my app, then I should redirect him back to Facebook?