# Setting up mailer for Rails 4.0

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, environment-variables, actionmailer

I was looking at this [video](http://railscasts.com/episodes/206-action-mailer-in-rails-3) along with the docs for Mailer class and I decided I would like to set up or try to set up the mail class for my app. The problem is I push my code to github so I don't want my gmail password being pushed with my code.

I have heard about environment variables for rails but cant find much on them let alone how to set one up in such that I can store my password in one and then just call it in and still be able to push my code to public repos.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4911607/is-it-possible-to-set-env-variables-for-rails-development-environment-in-my-code,.. my choice will be to define it in a separate file in `/config` folder and ignore it using `.gitignore`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found this useful:  http://railsapps.github.io/rails-environment-variables.html

RailsCasts #85 YAML Configuration (revised) also goes over some aspects of ENV variables and setting them up.