# Missing `secret_key_base` for 'production' environment

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, nginx

I have an error `Missing 'secret_key_base' for 'production' environment` in my nginx error.log. When I open my secrets.yml, I see:

```
development:
  secret_key_base: 123...

test:
  secret_key_base: 321...

# Do not keep production secrets in the repository,
# instead read values from the environment.
production:
  secret_key_base: <%= ENV["SECRET_KEY_BASE"] %>
```

Where SECRET_KEY_BASE is defined? Should I add it somewhere?

As a result, nginx shows `502 Bad Gateway` for my Rails App. Rails version 4.1.1

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It's expecting an environment variable that you can set either in your own code somewhere else, in your [bash profile](http://railsapps.github.io/rails-environment-variables.html), or in a [dotenv file](https://github.com/bkeepers/dotenv).

See [Is it possible to set ENV variables for rails development environment in my code?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4911607/is-it-possible-to-set-env-variables-for-rails-development-environment-in-my-code) for more details.

Personally I just put all my sensitive stuff directly in secrets.yml and just keep that out of the repository since that seems to be the intended purpose of that file.

Comment: NOTE: if you're using RVM, the "bash profile" approach is slightly different: you'll need to add the `export` line to `~/.rvm/environments/ruby-xxx`. See https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/rubyversionmanager/LF2DxnpSlQU

Answer (score 0):

Simple fix would be:

```
development:
  secret_key_base: 123...

test:
  secret_key_base: 321...

# Do not keep production secrets in the repository,
# instead read values from the environment.
production:
  secret_key_base: 123... # make/rebuild similar hash as defined in development and test variables
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's what I do in my production deployment script:

```
export SECRET_KEY_BASE=${SECRET_KEY_BASE:=`rake secret`}
```

This will occupy environment variable `SECRET_KEY_BASE` with the result of `rake secret` only if `SECRET_KEY_BASE` is empty.

Answer (score 0):

Note, if you are running Rails 4.2.5.1  (or maybe any flavor of Rails 4.2 ?), you might find that, even with secrets.yml present in the production directory, it is not getting picked up, if running WEBrick.  I'm running a small rails website, on a local LAN only (not exposed to world).  If I start (in production) using command line:

```
rails server -b 0.0.0.0 -p 3000 -e p
```

the webserver starts ok, but from the browser, I get the "Missing secret_token and secret_key_base for 'p' environment..." error.   But if I start the server with:

```
rails server -b 0.0.0.0 -p 3000 -e production
```

then everything works fine, as the secrets.yml file is accessed correctly. The string provided after the '-e' option determines which secret_key_base is picked up in the secrets.yml file.  Options are: "development:", "test:" and "production:", and the word must spelled out in full.