# db:migrate:reset doesn't work with environment variables

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, rake

The way I set up environment variables is like it was outlined [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4911607/is-it-possible-to-set-env-variables-for-rails-development-environment-in-my-code/11765775#11765775).

In other words I created a config/app_env_vars.rb file and put:

```
unless Rails.env.production?
  ENV['DB_PASSWORD'] = 'password'
  ENV['DB_USERNAME'] = 'username'
end
puts 'ECHO app_env_vars.rb'
```

In config/environment.rb I put:

```
app_env_vars = File.join(Rails.root, 'config', 'app_env_vars.rb')
load(app_env_vars) if File.exists?(app_env_vars)

puts "ECHO environment.rb"
```

right before `Rails.application.initialize!`

In database.yml:

```
development:
  adapter: postgresql
  encoding: unicode
  database: my_app_development
  host: localhost
  pool: 5
  password: <%= ENV['DB_PASSWORD'] %>

test:
  adapter: postgresql
  encoding: unicode
  database: my_app_test
  host: localhost
  pool: 5
  password: <%= ENV['DB_PASSWORD'] %>
```

When I run tasks such as `bundle exec rake db:migrate` and `bundle exec rake db:reset` it works fine but when I run `bundle exec rake db:migrate:reset` it will fail displaying:

```
fe_sendauth: no password supplied
.
.
.
Couldn't drop my_app_development
fe_sendauth: no password supplied
.
.
.
Couldn't drop my_app_test
fe_sendauth: no password supplied
ECHO app_env_vars.rb
ECHO environment.rb
```

Usually when I run bundle exec rake db:migrate (and db:drop) it will first display the ECHO parts and then do the task and out put the log. But in the case of the db:migrate:reset it won't initialize the environment variables until after the task.

When in database.yml I put the actual passwords rather than the env variables then the
db:migrate:reset works with no problem.

Here is rake db:migrate:reset with --trace option

```
** Invoke db:migrate:reset (first_time)
** Invoke db:drop (first_time)
** Invoke db:load_config (first_time)
** Execute db:load_config
** Execute db:drop
fe_sendauth: no password supplied
.
. # gem trace stuff...
.
Couldn't drop my_app_development
fe_sendauth: no password supplied
.
. # gem trace stuff...
.
Couldn't drop my_app_test
** Invoke db:create (first_time)
** Invoke db:load_config 
** Execute db:create
fe_sendauth: no password supplied
.
. # gem trace stuff...
.
Couldn't create database for {"adapter"=>"postgresql", "encoding"=>"unicode", "database"=>"my_app_development", "host"=>"localhost", "pool"=>5, "password"=>nil}
fe_sendauth: no password supplied
.
. # gem trace stuff...
.
Couldn't create database for {"adapter"=>"postgresql", "encoding"=>"unicode", "database"=>"my_app_test", "host"=>"localhost", "pool"=>5, "password"=>nil}
** Invoke db:migrate (first_time)
** Invoke environment (first_time)
** Execute environment
ECHO app_env_vars.rb
ECHO environment.rb
** Invoke db:load_config 
** Execute db:migrate
** Invoke db:_dump (first_time)
** Execute db:_dump
** Invoke db:schema:dump (first_time)
** Invoke environment 
** Invoke db:load_config 
** Execute db:schema:dump
** Execute db:migrate:reset
```

Here is the --trace for rake db:reset

```
** Invoke db:reset (first_time)
** Invoke environment (first_time)
** Execute environment
ECHO app_env_vars.rb
ECHO environment.rb
** Invoke db:load_config (first_time)
** Execute db:load_config
** Execute db:reset
** Invoke db:drop (first_time)
** Invoke db:load_config 
** Execute db:drop
** Invoke db:setup (first_time)
** Invoke db:schema:load_if_ruby (first_time)
** Invoke db:create (first_time)
** Invoke db:load_config 
** Execute db:create
** Invoke environment 
** Execute db:schema:load_if_ruby
** Invoke db:schema:load (first_time)
** Invoke environment 
** Invoke db:load_config 
** Execute db:schema:load
-- enable_extension("plpgsql")
   -> 0.0772s
-- create_table("users", {:force=>true})
   -> 0.0795s
-- add_index("users", ["email"], {:name=>"index_users_on_email", :unique=>true, :using=>:btree})
   -> 0.0406s
-- initialize_schema_migrations_table()
   -> 0.0829s
** Invoke db:structure:load_if_sql (first_time)
** Invoke db:create 
** Invoke environment 
** Execute db:structure:load_if_sql
** Invoke db:seed (first_time)
** Execute db:seed
** Invoke db:abort_if_pending_migrations (first_time)
** Invoke environment 
** Execute db:abort_if_pending_migrations
** Execute db:setup
```

In the case of `db:reset` the `** Execute environment` part is done before any executions, while with `db:migrate:reset` the `** Execute environment` is done after a few executions

Comment: Why don't you handle env variables with application.yml ? it works out of the box.

Comment: Did you mean application.rb? Since I can't find application.yml. I am using rails 4.1.6

I use it this way because I understand it is 'good practice' and also because when I upload to github I don't want other members to see sensitive information.

Comment: From my understanding env variables are defined in the system (os) rather than in the app. You can pass the to the rake task as well 'DB_PASSWORD=123 rake db:migrate'

Comment: They can also be defined by the app, or all put in a single file.

Thanks for the rake task.

The point of this question is to find out why is the rake db:migrate:reset behaving differently than rake db:reset for example.

Answer (score 0):

The reason why this setup (setting env variables in a file then load them trough environment.rb) doesn't work is because active record can be used outside rails therefore now every task runs with initialized rails environment.

A better solution is to use gems like [figaro](https://github.com/laserlemon/figaro) or [dot-env](https://github.com/bkeepers/dotenv) which will load with every rake task. How exactly is that done with those gems I am not sure but if I get into it and find out I'll post here.