# Rails - Paperclip can't load s3 bucket name

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, paperclip

I get the following error ArgumentError, missing required :bucket option

Looks like an error where Paperclip can't load the url because it can't find the :bucket name

I had my s3 credentials hardcoded for the development environment. Everything worked fine. To make the application more secure I moved it.

```
config\initializers\dev_config.rb
ENV.update YAML.load_file("#{Rails.root}/config/dev_vars.yml")[Rails.env]

config\dev_vars.yml
development:
  S3_BUCKET_NAME: "####"
  AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID: "#####"
  AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY: "####"

config/environments/development.rb
config.paperclip_defaults = {
 :storage => :s3,
 :s3_credentials => {
  :bucket => ENV['S3_BUCKET_NAME'],
  :access_key_id => ENV['AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID'],
  :secret_access_key => ENV['AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY']
 }
}
```

I can't seem to figure out what is wrong

- I've checked the YAML file is properly formatted
- Running `ENV['S3_BUCKET_NAME']` in the console gives the correct name

Can anyone help?

*EDIT -*

What I have done is hardcoded just the bucket name `:bucket => "name"` And that has worked, however I do not want to hardcode s3 information for security reasons.

Is there a reason the other variables are loaded but not the bucket name?

Comment: Try setting `ENV` directly without the yaml file

Comment: Sorry I don't understand how would I do that?

Comment: See here the solution: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4911607/is-it-possible-to-set-env-variables-for-rails-development-environment-in-my-code

Comment: I initially did set ENV variables without the YAML file, however that is not secure so I put them in configuration yaml. It looks like an issue only with the `:bucket` variable